# Android Studio How to print on screen a variable content (number)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, android-studio

```
private EditText InputWiek;     //First input
    private EditText InputTspocz;   //Second input
    private TextView textout;

    float Wiek = InputWiek;
    float Tspocz = InputTspocz;

    int Tmax = 220-Wiek;
    int RT = Tmax-Tspocz;
    int Tburn = 70*RT/100+Tspocz;

    public void buttonOnClick(View v) {

        Button button=(Button) v;

        InputWiek = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idWiek);
        InputTspocz = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idTspocz)
        textout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOutput;
        textout.setText(Tburn.getText()));                    //A little scrap here :/




    }
}
```

Comment: `Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Stuff you wanna write out");`

Comment: At textout = ..their is a missing ) befor ; and in the next line is a ) to mutch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `String.valeuOf(Tburn)`